# What is happening to NCurses and OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, ncurses

Apparently libncurses...dylib is broken OS X 10.6.3 relative to Mutt, and perhaps other applications, that use ncurses, although it works in 10.6 (as I can attest) and reportedly it works in 10.6.2.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or a feature in the view of Apple?  If a feature, is there a workaround for people who want to upgrade 10.6..., but also want to use, for example, Mutt?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As your post is pretty sparse in details, I guess you're talking about the bug in ncurses that breaks the way arrows works? (And may quit programs when you try to use the arrows, as a side effect)

I described it here: http://www.uponmyshoulder.com/blog/2010/os-x-10-6-3-broke-ncurses/

If we're talking about the same thing, I honestly think this is a bug. It doesn't match the documentation for ncurses, and actually makes no sense.

I submitted a bug report more than two weeks ago, without any answer from Apple so far.

A workaround (as suggested by Jonathan Groll) is to copy /usr/lib/libncurses.5.4.dylib and /usr/lib/libncurses.5.dylib from a 10.6.2 system. I don't really know what to think about such a libraries switch, as it might trigger other problems, but it does indeed fix this bug.

Comment: Could you upload/send me the 10.6.2 verisons of the lib-files?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have them any more. Maybe you could try recompiling from the sources...

... An hour and a half later, I tried to recompile myself and got it to work:
http://www.uponmyshoulder.com/blog/2010/fix-ncurses-in-os-x-10-6-3/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've been told by Apple that my bug (ID #7812788) is a known issue currently being investigated by engineering, and has been filled as a duplicate of bug #7812932.

I'll keep you updated. :)